# Do Google charts store data?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm reading the Terms of use which can be found here: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/terms.html

But I do not see anything telling how Google use the data provided to generate the charts. Can someone be kind and enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Privacy Policy is likely to apply here. The relevant part should be:

> Log information – When you access
>   Google services via a browser,
>   application or other client our
>   servers automatically record certain
>   information. These server logs may
>   include information such as your web
>   request, your interaction with a
>   service, Internet Protocol address,
>   browser type, browser language, the
>   date and time of your request and one
>   or more cookies that may uniquely
>   identify your browser or your account.

In combination with

> Affiliated Google Services on other
>   sites – We offer some of our services
>   on or through other web sites.
>   Personal information that you provide
>   to those sites may be sent to Google
>   in order to deliver the service. We
>   process such information under this
>   Privacy Policy

Because you send the chart information with the URI and thus they will at least log it.